# Ruby on rails: Select options menu with default value attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

I need to produce a select menu with a Default value on the list of `<options>` . Here is how I need it looks like.

```
<select name="menu[parent_id]" id="menu_parent_id">
 <option value="0">==None==</option>
 <option value="34">TEST</option>
</select>
```

Currently I use this `select` helper in my form

```
   <%= f.select(:parent_id, @parent_menus.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {:include_blank => '==None=='})%>
```

the above code produce this; (`value=""`)

```
<select name="menu[parent_id]" id="menu_parent_id">
 <option value="">==None==</option>
 <option value="34">TEST</option>
</select>
```

Does anyone here can show me a way to add `value="0"` to the options list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<%= f.select(:parent_id, [["==None==", 0]] + @parent_menus.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }) %>
```

Comment: Here is what I get for that,

`<option value="==None==">==None==</option><option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>`

Actually I'm looking for something like this

`<option value="0">==None==</option>`

Comment: Hooray it worked! thanks a bunch Simone. I'll make this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<%= f.select(:parent_id, options_for_select(["==None==", 0] + @parent_menus.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, 0)) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thought I would add this to anyone looking to do a **default selected value that is one of the objects in the dropdown**, as opposed to a 'none' value.  ie, you are editing a form that has a previous value selected, and you don't want to lose that previous value on your edit page:

Assuming you have an array of parents held in @parents and your form is tied to an object called @my_messed_up_family, and @my_messed_up_family has one 'father':

```
= f.label :parent_id, "Choose which of your parents is your father?

= f.select :parent_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@parents.sort_by {|n| n.name}, "id", "name", :selected=>@my_messed_up_family.father.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

**I don't know this is Ruby way or not But this will definietly work**

```
<%= f.select(:parent_id, "<option value='0'>Please select</option>"+options_for_select(@parent_menus.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }))%>
```

EDITED. For pre-selected according to the value save in database i assume @user is your object contain the database value for following example.

```
<%= f.select(:parent_id, "<option value='0'>Please select</option>"+options_for_select(@parent_menus.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, @user.id ))%>
```

Comment: please check my Edited Answer hope that helps.